# Placement of warm inlet vs cool outlet for best water cooling design

Tags: thermodynamics

I am conducting a small trial and have a reservoir and coils inside running refrigerant. The coils are to cool the water. I will have warm water coming into the reservoir and chilled water going out. How should I set up the warm water inlet and cool water outlet for the best cooling affect? Inlet or outlet on top or bottom? Should I put the warm water inlet on bottom and the cold water outlet on top so that the warm water will rise and mix with the cold? Should I put the inlet and outlet on the same side of the reservoir or on opposite ends? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and have a great day.

Comment: If the runs of coil are relatively straight, you might consider putting in baffles, so that the water has to flow across the coils (rather than parallel to the coils).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Baffling sounds like an excellent idea.

Answer (score 1):

best heat transfer occurs in the *counterflow* regime, where the water to be chilled enters the reservoir tank next to where the refrigerant coil exits the tank, and the chilled water leaves the tank next to where the cold refrigerant line enters the tank. This works best when the tank is a relatively long cylinder and not so well when the tank is a cube or a large rectangular affair.

Comment: Thank you Nielson! Did a bit of poking around on the topic of counterflow and am inspired to try some new ideas.